# Fetch details through API from the secondary table using Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, api, django-rest-framework

I'm new to Django,

Having two databases,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'global_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abc123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': ''
    },
    'usersdb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'users',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'abc123',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': ''
    }
}
```

Created required models and serializers separately. setup required views in views.py class.

i'm getting the below error

```
1146, "Table 'global_db.account_categories' doesn't exist"
```

the table actually exists in my secondary database 'users', can anyone please help me out what i'm doing wrong.

models.py

```html
class AccountCategories(models.Model):
    company_id = models.IntegerField()
    category_type = models.IntegerField()
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.IntegerField()
    created_by = models.IntegerField()
    modified_by = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    modified = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'account_categories'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you migrate the databases

Comment: When does this error occur ? At migration time ? At running time (`python manage.py runserver`) ?

Comment: Yes i did the migrations for the 2 databases

Comment: @TonyEight Runtime. After running the development server.

Comment: Can you add snippets of your `models.py` to your question ? Do you use database routing ?

Comment: @TonyEight added models.py code. No till now i haven't set database routing can you please provide me any reference. Thanks.

Comment: Database routing is made to address specific usage, such as if you want to use a specific database for specific apps/models. You can find [a working example in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/#an-example).

But if you did launch the `migrate` commands as suggested by @kostadin-slavov, all your models should have been created on both databases. So, since you're new to **Django**, I wonder if you also did `makemigrations` part of the migration process ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177707/discussion-between-tonyeight-and-madhup).

Answer (score 0):

On migrating if you use 2 databses you should specify all the time which database to migrate

otherwise will migrate only the default one

```
 ./manage.py migrate --database=usersdb

 ./manage.py migrate --database=default
```

Comment: Yes, i did the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I just saw your `class Meta`

You've set `managed = False` so it is logical that the table is not created during the migration process : [see the docs about it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#managed).

Try remove this line and go through the migration process again.